# First time installing but expiration date is in past Navicat

Tags: navicat

I just downloaded navicat, I did not use it before 101% so why I have expiration date in past?

Is there a file on system where can I delete something if it somehow contains something that moves expiration date to 25.6.?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 6):

I guess you 're in windows according to your GUI here :)
To give you another free trial of navicat!

- uninstall Navicat
- run regedit
- open HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software
- delete the PremiumSoft folder
- re-install Navicat

Comment: Nice tip, thanks. But why did I get navicat there if I installed for first time? :D

Comment: Yes You Won't but will Get More Votes in Days to come

Comment: I did that. But Expiration date is still same (

Answer (score 2):

you do not have to uninstall, just change the system date, a date before expiration,

This work for me.
But I'm sure the date is around, the big question is, where?

Comment: My case was not like in the question, I was trying to get my queries back after trial expiration. This totally worked.